# LEFT JOIN returning all null values

Tags: mysql, null, left-join

So my query is returning the correct amount of results, but for some reason the left join results are all NULL values. Here is the query:

```
SELECT invoices.* FROM appointments
LEFT JOIN invoices ON 'appointments.invoice_guid' = 'invoices.guid'
```

Results

```
guid       created_at      status
NULL       NULL            NULL
NULL       NULL            NULL
```

Tables

```
invoices
    - guid
    - created_at
    - status

appointments
    - guid
    - created_at
    - status
    - invoice_guid
```

Comment: `'appointments.invoice_guid' = 'invoices.guid'`Because it's always false...

Comment: @Selvin How is it always false??

Comment: Because you are comparing strings not a values in columns

Comment: @Selvin Yes, but the strings are equal to each other

Comment: Literal "appointments.invoice_guid" is not equal "invoices.guid"

Comment: I see what you mean now, ha ha. Couldn't see the forest for the trees, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using quotation marks in a wrong way, just remove them

```
SELECT invoices.* 
FROM appointments
LEFT JOIN invoices ON appointments.invoice_guid = invoices.guid
```

The way you are using them is comparing two strings, and they are different so you don´t JOIN anything

Answer (score 0):

remove the single quotes 'appointments.invoice_guid' = 'invoices.guid'